# WiX Toolset Extension: How to make an order of a Custom Action configurable?

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix-extension

I am in progress with a custom WiX Toolset Extension and would like to know, if it is possible to make a custom action's order configurable?

For example, I have two actions:

1. **CreateFolder** Custom Action:

   CustomAction Id="CreateFolder" BinaryKey="My.Ext.CA" DllEntry="CreateFolder" Execute="deferred"
2. **ExecuteSql** Custom Action:

   CustomAction Id="ExecuteSql" BinaryKey="My.Ext.CA" DllEntry="ExecuteSql" Execute="deferred"

They are placed in the InstallExecuteSequence in the next order:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="CreateFolder" After="InstallValidate">
                NOT Installed
            </Custom>

            <Custom Action="ExecuteSql" Before="InstallFinalize">
                NOT Installed
            </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

It works fine for executing CreateFolder CA first, and then ExecuteSql.
But, in some cases it is required for WixExtension user to run ExecuteSql first, and CreateFolder comes next.

Can I somehow specify a CA order to be executed within InstallExecuteSequence and make it configurable?

Comment: I would hope that someone creating a wix extension has a very solid understanding of custom action design.  It's kinda like writing classes for the .NET Base Class Libraries.  Only the very best developers wield that responsibility.   I'd be willing to discuss design considerations with you in private if you'd like.